# open "non-secure" blank window from a secure page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the following code to open a blank window from a "secure" page:

```
$('#previewTemplate').click(function () {
            var preview = window.open('', 'PreviewTemplate', 'width=800,height=400,scrollbars=1');
            var html = '<html><head><title>Preview</title></head><body>' + $("#textbox").val() + '</body></html>';
            preview.document.open("text/html", "replace"); preview.document.write(html); preview.document.close(); return false;
        });
```

The blank window is opening as a secure page (preview.document.location.protocol="https:") so IE is barking about the mixed content because I have a non-secure image in the page. I'm trying to open up the blank window as a non-secure window. Trying to change the location.protocol to "http:" or location.port to 80 doesn't seem to work. Is it possible to open up a blank "non-secure" window from within a secure page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the main window was https and the child window was http, the same origin policy would prevent the two from communicating with each other.  i.e. those calls to preview.document.open would never work.

Three options:

- host the image from the same https
  domain as the parent window.
- Instead of dynamically writing to the child window, just host a page on
  the same server as the image.  Even
  if you can only put static html there
  for whatever reason, some basic
  javascript could be used to read the
  url's query string and get the value
  of textbox.
- Read up on [window.postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.postMessage).  Only works
  in more modern browsers though.

Comment: Can't use option 1 since the image is hosted off site in a cdn that doesn't support https. I'm just going to host the preview page instead of using document.write; that will allow me to open the child window as http:.